# Insert Large Amount of Raw Data into Database PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a question on what's the best way to insert large amounts of raw data into the database.

The raw data looks like this (It's a lot more but I don't think I need to use everything for my example):

CUSACODE - GAME - CONSOLE - REGION - DOWNLOADURL

```
CUSA00475   Akiba's Trip 2  PS4 JP  http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/appkgo/prod/CUSA00475_00/4/f_28d6a38b6ebac96d17a8b4de7616f6e5de43da365ef30d8354fb55df94eb0a4a/f/JP0048-CUSA00475_00-AKIBASNEXTAPP000.pkg
CUSA00363   Alien: Isolation - 0    PS4 US  http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/appkgo/prod/CUSA00363_00/3/f_e0ebc06845e6271392d9e3060bed29f7a1fb71bc4d8a966714ddc6df50934638/f/UP0177-CUSA00363_00-ALIENISOLATIONP4_0.pkg
CUSA00363   Alien: Isolation - 1    PS4 US  http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/appkgo/prod/CUSA00363_00/3/f_e0ebc06845e6271392d9e3060bed29f7a1fb71bc4d8a966714ddc6df50934638/f/UP0177-CUSA00363_00-ALIENISOLATIONP4_1.pkg
CUSA00363   Alien: Isolation - 2    PS4 US  http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/appkgo/prod/CUSA00363_00/3/f_e0ebc06845e6271392d9e3060bed29f7a1fb71bc4d8a966714ddc6df50934638/f/UP0177-CUSA00363_00-ALIENISOLATIONP4_2.pkg
```

Separated using a whitespace.

So I've thought it would be a good practice to first make an array of it. Once it's in the array, loop it through a `while` and in the `while` a SQL INSERT query.

Or would it be better to make a SQL query for this? Are there any ways to generate this SQL query so I don't have to add everything manually?

I've tried doing this:

```
$data = "CUSA00475|Akiba's Trip 2|PS4|JP|http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/appkgo/prod/CUSA00475_00/4/f_28d6a38b6ebac96d17a8b4de7616f6e5de43da365ef30d8354fb55df94eb0a4a/f/JP0048-CUSA00475_00-AKIBASNEXTAPP000.pkg,
CUSA00363|Alien: Isolation - 0|PS4|US|http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/appkgo/prod/CUSA00363_00/3/f_e0ebc06845e6271392d9e3060bed29f7a1fb71bc4d8a966714ddc6df50934638/f/UP0177-CUSA00363_00-ALIENISOLATIONP4_0.pkg,
CUSA00363|Alien: Isolation - 1|PS4|US|http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/appkgo/prod/CUSA00363_00/3/f_e0ebc06845e6271392d9e3060bed29f7a1fb71bc4d8a966714ddc6df50934638/f/UP0177-CUSA00363_00-ALIENISOLATIONP4_1.pkg,
CUSA00363|Alien: Isolation - 2|PS4|US|http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/appkgo/prod/CUSA00363_00/3/f_e0ebc06845e6271392d9e3060bed29f7a1fb71bc4d8a966714ddc6df50934638/f/UP0177-CUSA00363_00-ALIENISOLATIONP4_2.pkg";

$result = explode("|", $data);

foreach($result as $res) {
        $sub = explode(",",$res);
        $mainCategory[$sub[0]] = explode("|",$sub[1]);
}
```

But that terribly failed. I hope someone can help me out with this!

Comment: Whats wrong with making a SQL INSERT inside the while-loop? Whats your problem there?

Comment: Are your raw data in a file? Better to not load all the data in memory (if you have a large amount of it).

Comment: @FabianN. I don't know how to put this information into an array, so I can use the array to insert it into a database.

Comment: what the second explode is about? The one in the `foreach` loop?

Comment: @NMoeini Figured I would have to separate  each line using a comma,

Comment: So you need to swap those explodes. Creating an array of lines and then an array of records out of each line.

Comment: Where this data come from? Is it in a file? If yes, what is the file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a large amount of data involved, a good idea would be using a prepared statement, which you initialze before the loop. Then inside you loop you bind the current data and execute the statement.

This would look something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tableName(CUSACODE, GAME, CONSOLE, REGION, DOWNLOADURL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$pstmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

foreach($allData as $data){
    $pstmt->bind_param("sssss", $data[0],  $data[1],  $data[2],  $data[3],  $data[4]);
    $pstmt->execute();
}

$pstmt->close();
```

For how you make the loop over the data are several approaches, depending how you data is stored.

For example, if your data is saved as a text file somewhere, you could use something like this:

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tableName(CUSACODE, GAME, CONSOLE, REGION, DOWNLOADURL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $pstmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

        $data = explode("\t", $line); //if the original delimiter is a tab, which was guessed, because only "whietspace" would make no sense

        $pstmt->bind_param("sssss", $data[0],  $data[1],  $data[2],  $data[3],  $data[4]);
        $pstmt->execute();
    }

    fclose($handle);
    $pstmt->close();
}
```

**EDIT**: Having the data inmemory already transformed to you `|` and `,` format, you certainly would first make a loop over `explode(',', $data)` and then explode with the`|`, so something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tableName(CUSACODE, GAME, CONSOLE, REGION, DOWNLOADURL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$pstmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

$seperatedData = explode(',', $data);

foreach($seperatedData as $oneDataSet){
    $seperatedOneData = explode('|', oneDataSet);

    $pstmt->bind_param("sssss", $seperatedOneData[0],  $seperatedOneData[1],  $seperatedOneData[2],  $seperatedOneData[3],  $seperatedOneData[4]);
    $pstmt->execute();
}

$pstmt->close();
```

Comment: IMHO, this would explode in case of a large data set or a large file.

Comment: @M Noeini, the in memory approach, sure, but the reading file line-by-line is totally fine, because when one line is too much for the memory, then Mitch should nonethelesss consider reading the data in a different way

Comment: So I modified your first code to my needs (was too late reading your edit), but it gives me $data is undefined. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Try to declare `$data` before using it? ;) Meaning first doing the explode, then tring to bind it to the statement. AND, there was a reason, why the declaring of the `$spmt` was before the loop

Comment: @FabianN. How stopid of me. It worked perfectly, thank you so much. Will accept your answer. :)